# htacces RewriteRule does not trigger on every request

Tags: .htaccess

We just tested an extension for a CMS which aims to create .webp images for other formats and deliver this .webp version to the browser instead of the original.

The key is this .htaccess RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.$2.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(fileadmin/.+)\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$ $1.$2.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]
```

But this rule only triggers sometimes.
Eg. for a page with 4 images the browser randomly receives the .jpg version or the .webp version of each image. Both versions exist in a subdirectory of "./fileadmin/" directory along each other (e.g. someimage.jpg and someimage.jpg.webp).
It does not depend on the image. Each of the images on a page shows this behaviour - sometimes .jpg, sometimes .webp.

Any idea what can be the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the request in the network traffic? Is the `Accept` HTTP request header being consistently sent in the request? Are images being cached on the client (although in that case you would still consistently get one or the other and not both). You have omitted the `L` flag, so processing continues through the file - do you have other directives? You probably should have the `L` flag on this directive.

Comment: `Accept` header is always sent - on each request there are some images sent as .webp, some others not. I tried the L flag already - the behaviour does not change.

Comment: Is it always the same images that are served as image/jpg (or image/webp) or is it seemingly random and changes between requests? Do all images have an associated `.webp` file? If so (or at least find a page where this is true) you can try (temporarily) removing the second `RewriteCond` directive that performs the filesystem check.

Comment: Also, where is this `.htaccess` file? And is there a `RewriteBase` directive set? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: @ArturCichosz Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MrWhite Hi, sorry for not coming back to you. I dropped this problem to work on another things at the time and forgoit about it.
I will evaluate this issue, once I deal with webp again

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu As statet above. I did not bother with it further at the time

Comment: Unfortunately, without further information this question is impossible to answer. On the face of it, this should work OK, but it depends on other factors which have not been stated, ie. the filenames being used, state of intermediary caches and possibly other directives in the `.htaccess` files(s) and server config. One thing of note, however, (from looking at your directives) is that your `.webp` images would seem to be named `<filename>.jpg.webp` ie. with 2 extensions? This could potentially cause problems for Apache. But if this is the case then your rule could also be simplified. (?)